Is every transformation a linear transformation of the form $S_A$ or $T_A$?
Here is the question I am trying to understand its solution:
For any matrix $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb R),$ we may define transformations $T_A, S_A \in \mathcal{L}(\operatorname{Mat}_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb R))$ by $T_A(X) = AX$ and $S_A(X) = XA.$ Is every linear transformation in $\mathcal{L}(\operatorname{Mat}_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb R))$ a linear transformation of the form $S_A$ or $T_A$ for some $A \in \operatorname{Mat}_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb R)$?
My gut feeling is yes as I saw this question here "*A transformation $T$ is linear if and only if it is a matrix transformation of the form $T=T_A$.*" Is this theorem true?
I am guessing I can prove this by considering the transpose but I do not know how. Could anyone clarify this to me please?
Or I can show that $T$ and $S$ are linear maps from $\operatorname{Mat}_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb R)$ to  $\mathcal{L}(\operatorname{Mat}_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb R))$ but I do not know how to show this either.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Take the transpose map $X\mapsto X^t$, if such a matrix $A$ exists, $A$ must be  the identity, but not every matrix is symmetric.

can you provide more details please @JorgeS. Is this proof valid for the given 2 types of transformations?

JUst a comment: the $T_A$ in your referenced question is not your $T_A$. So the reference is irrelevant/misleading. @JorgeS. has given you the counterexample you need to examine.

By the way, here's an interesting related result.

@Intuition sorry for the late reply, if $A$ is a matrix such that $T_A$ is equal to the transpose map, then $AI=T_A(I)=I^t$ this implies that $A=I$. If $X$ is any matrix then $X =IX= T_A(X) =X^t$. A similar argument works for $S_A$.

@ancientmathematician thank you very much for pointing this out

No. First of all, you should also consider maps of the form $T_A + S_{A'}$. But even then it's not enough.
If $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space, then $\mathrm{End}(V)$ is a vector space of dimension $n^2$.
In your case, $V$ has dimension $9$, so $\mathrm{End}(V)$ has dimension $81$. But your examples only provide a subspace of dimension $9 + 9 = 18$.
I believe that all linear maps are given by sums of linear maps of the form $S_{A'} \circ T_A$, mapping $X \mapsto AXA'$.

Apart from the dimension argument in the other answer, it should be easy to construct a linear map $L$ that cannot possibly be equal to any $T_A$ or $S_A$. For example, pick any two mutually orthogonal unit vectors $u$ and $v$. Define $B=vu^T+uv^T$ and $L:X\mapsto BXB$. Then $L(uu^T)=Buu^TB=(Bu)(Bu)^T=vv^T$. Therefore $L(uu^T)v=v$ and $v^TL(uu^T)=v^T$. However, $T_A(uu^T)v$ and $v^TS_A(uu^T)$ are zero regardless of the choice of $A$.
